# Pendulum-related derivation

Tags: classical-mechanics

In Spivak's [lecture notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Eshifrin/Spivak_physics.pdf) on mechanics (page 16), it states
$$\hspace{2 cm} a_{\theta}=g\sin{\theta} , \hspace{2 cm} (1)$$ where $\theta$ is the angle made by the pendulum string with the vertical and $a_{\theta}$ is the tangential acceleration. I understand where the above equation comes from. They then proceed:

> "If we consider $\theta$ as a function of time, and let $l$ be the length of the string... then equation $(1)$ yields $$\theta '' +\frac{g}{l}\sin{\theta}=0.$$
> "

How is this obtained from $(1)$? (Sorry if I am missing something obvious here.)

Comment: What is that ^" thing above theta

Comment: I think it means the second derivative with respect to time.

Comment: what is a theta supposed to mean then?

Comment: The angle between the pendulum string and the downward-pointing vertical axis at a given time.

Comment: hmm you could try looking at pendulum formulas... g/l should be quite straightforward right

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see why it's straightforward (haven't done any pendulum physics before).

Answer (score 0):

Attempted answer: 
<s>Let's look at the motion of the bob as it moves from the lowest point ($\theta =0$) to some higher-up point. We'll assume no swinging back and forth for now (I'm not sure if this matters, but I don't want to worry about it just yet).</s>
^Now that I think of it, this stuff probably isn't a problem?

Let's treat our path as a line.

Our position is given by $$x=\theta \cdot l. $$
(This is because we're moving in a circle, and the length of the arc of a circle subtended by the angle $\theta$ is $2 \pi  l \cdot \frac{\theta}{2 \pi}=l \cdot \theta$. But since we're sort of "flattening out" our tangential axis, this really gives us our position. We'll assume that the "lowest" point in our 2-D arc corresponds to a position $0$).

Now, $$x'=l \frac{d \theta}{dt}$$
$$x''=l \frac{d^2 \theta}{dt^2}=a_{\theta}.$$

So from $(1)$, $$a_{\theta}=l \frac{d^2 \theta}{dt^2}=g\sin\theta$$
$$\frac{d^2 \theta}{dt^2}=\frac{g}{l}\sin{\theta}$$
$$\frac{d^2 \theta}{dt^2}-\frac{g}{l}\sin{\theta}=0.$$

Comment: Haven't you already arrived with your answer here? $d^2θ/dt^2$ is the $θ^"$

Comment: Hopefully! (Unless I've made some assumptions that I shouldn't have...? ) I came up with this after asking the question. I wasn't expecting for so many steps to be skipped in the notes.

Comment: They probably assume you know this already.  Sorry if I couldn't help because I have currently learnt very little only

Comment: No problem. I know almost no physics. I just started messing around with it, so I'm afraid I'm always making easy mistakes. (I'm not too sure about all the coordinate-axis tinkering that I've done... )